# how to reference the path parameters in react router dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

```
<Route path="users">
  <Route path=":id" element={<UserProfile id={":id"} />} />
</Route>
```

The above is what I am trying to do. The code isn't correct. How to make it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route path params are located on a `params` object accessible by the [`useParams`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-params) hook.

> The `useParams` hook returns an object of key/value pairs of the
> dynamic params from the current URL that were matched by the `<Route path>`. Child routes inherit all params from their parent routes.

For a given route:

```
<Route path=":id" element={<UserProfile />} />
```

The `UserProfile` component will use the `useParams` hook to access the `id` route path param.

Example:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const UserProfile = () => {
  ...

  const { id } = useParams();

  ...

};
```

If the `UserProfile` component can't use React hooks directly for some reason and takes `id` as a prop, then create a wrapper component to use the hook and inject the prop.

Example:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const UserProfileWrapper = () => {
  ...

  const { id } = useParams();

  ...

  return <UserProfile id={id} />;
};
```

...

```
<Route path="users">
  <Route path=":id" element={<UserProfileWrapper />} />
</Route>
```